# How to tidily integrate power into an island

Tags: electrical, kitchens, kitchen-counters

I'm currently running the ducts for wiring into my gutted kitchen and was wondering how best to integrate power into my island.

I've seen pop-up products like [this](http://www.powerdock.co.za/pdo-mk2.asp) and [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002B4EPOA) that fit nicely into the island, but am not sure of whether they're actually practical.

Also, I'm unsure of how to wire the island. Do I wire a plug directly into the cabinet?

Comment: My brother has this type of socket in his kitchen. They look like they're what you want. However, I haven't cooked in his kitchen so I can't speak from personal experience.

Comment: A picture of the island plans might help in suggesting possible receptacle locations.

Answer (score 10):

I looked at the link you posted, personally, I think it looks a bit gimmicky and perhaps impracticable if you use it regularly. I think you would be well served with permanently built in GFCI receptacles. I would suggest that they be built into the sides of the island.  (never the top)  Assuming the island is fixed in position, simply run wires up from under the floor, install device boxes in the left and right side panels of your island. You can use old work plastic boxes with retainer tabs. Using the box as a template, trace the shape on your cabinet panel, cut it out with a jig saw, install the box, bring your wires up from below, wire the GFCI, done.  Now you will have electrical power available from either side,and not have to worry about dirt or liquids getting into them. Good Luck

Comment: If you install the receptacles on the sides of the island, make sure they are not in a place where fingers would likely be in harms way. for example if you were to rest your hand on the edge of the counter top and naturally wrap your fingers around the edge, don't have a receptacle too close to where your fingers would be.  This is a more common problem with receptacles on the sides of bathroom vanities, but could also apply in this situation.

Comment: and  make sure where you put the outlets doesn't interfere with drawers or stick out in an unsightly manner in to a cabinet.

Comment: very good caveat longneck!!!!!  gotta plan ahead for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Our island has 130mm overhangs on each end (plus 300mm overhand on the front for stools). We simply had a power point installed under the overhang on the far side of the island where it is not visible. Note the crappy location (we wanted it on the flat part of the panel), this was caused by clashing with the drawer runners in the island. If I had know this upfront, I may have chosen a different power point.

I looked at the pop-up power points, but I think our solution was simpler, cheaper and better looking.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how tidy you want it, you can also wire a box up inside one of the cabinets, it just means that you'll have to open the cabinet door to actually make use of the outlet.

I've seen people do it under sinks for plugging in garbage disposals (which I don't think it allowed by code in all areas), or inside cabinets that have an [appliance lift](http://www.ovisonline.com/store/detail.asp?product_id=RAS-ML-HDCR) so you can just leave the mixer plugged in.  (although, you have to turn the mixer sideways ... it won't go into the cabinet the way they show it in the picture)